# Instead of getting pushed to array I get error

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this budget app. The idea as of right now is in the markup you pick a type (income or expense), add a description of said type, and enter the value. (expense, buy car, 2500) and it should push to an array in the data object, instead I keep getting an error on line 30. (error is commented on line)

```
// BUDGET CONTROLLER
var budgetController = (function() {
var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
};
var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
};
var data = {
    allItems:{
        exp: [],
        inc:[]
    },
    totals: {
        exp: 0,
        inc: 0
    }
};
return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val) {
        var newItem, ID;
        //[1 2 3 4 5], next ID = 6
        //[1 2 4 6 8], next ID = 9
        // ID = last ID + 1
        // Create new ID
        if (data.allItems[type].length > 0){ //ERROR THROWN HERE
            ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
        } else {
            ID = 0;
        };
        // Create new item based on 'inc' or 'exp' type
        if(type === 'exp') {
            newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
        } else if (type === 'inc') {
            newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
        };
        // Push it into our data structure
        data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
        // Return the new element
        return newItem;
},
testing: function() {
    console.log(data);
    }
};
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enter the value. (expense, buy car, 2500) and it should push to an array in the data object, instead i keep getting and error on line 30.

The reason is that you're passing `expense` as the first parameter to the `addItem` function which is used to access `data.allItems`.

However `expense` doesn't exist in `data.allItems` at all which, if I'm not mistaken, will throw an error about trying to access `.length` of `undefined`.

So either you change the `exp` key in `data.allItems` to `expenses` or you pass `exp` to the `addItem` function instead.

*In terms of code readability, going with `expenses` is more suitable in this scenario.*